# how to avoid (gratuitous?) addslashes happening (apparently) in Zend\Form or Zend\View

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

I have a Zend\Form\Form validating and filtering input which is sent to a database and an email message, and I notice that the quote characters are escaped by backslashes, as in:

`I\'ve seen \"fire\" and I\'ve seen \"rain\"`

Before you say magic_quotes_gpc: I am using php 5.6. And Zend Framework 2.5 components as standalones (no MVC). I am rendering my elements semi-manually with

```
echo  $view->formElement($element);
```

I am not running my input through any filters that would do this, just things like StringTrim. I have used Zend\Form and friends in mvc context doing similar things, with the same versions of everything, and not getting this result.

Do I have to call stripslashes() on my data before doing something with it? That's kind of ugly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're running PHP 5.6? I'd suggest adding a `phpinfo();` page to make sure. Also try creating a standalone PHP page (no ZF)  with a form and see if you see the same behaviour.

Comment: thanks for validating my reasoning and troubleshooting methods :-) ! You've enumerated the first two things I did.  PHP 5.6.10: check. Make a little test page, with ZF2 stripped out: check. The unescaped double-quote gives you premature field termination as you'd expect, but there ain't no backslashes. I run `$_POST['string']`  through `htmlspecialchars()` before printing it as an input field value, and it works as it should. I think some ZF2 2.6 component is being excessively helpful. I've examined the source, grepped like crazy, can't figure it out. Working around with `stripslashes()`

Comment: There really isn't any reason for any ZF2 component to try and escape data in that way since ZF was always designed to be run without magic quotes. If you want to fix it I'd suggest gradually adding in ZF components to your test page until it starts breaking. So start by introducing Zend\Form, and so on.

Comment: that would be the Right Thing To Do, and I will, time permitting, and come back to tell the world how it turned out. Thanks.